# JavaScript: Extract one number value out of key-value array and store them in a Variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I do an InfluxDB query and get exact one result row like this:

```
{"result":[[{"result":"_result","table":0,"_start":"2022-01-28T09:00:12.676771291Z","_stop":"2022-01-29T09:00:12.676771291Z","_measurement":"Strom.Heizung.Energie_in_der_letzten_Stunde","_value":14.683000000000117,"_time":"2022-01-29T09:00:12.676771291Z","ts":1643446812676}]],"ts":1643446812684,"error":null}
```

I need the value of the *_value* key in a variable e.g. *value*. In this example the 14.683000000000117

I tried it with the map-function:

```
value = query.result[0].map(elm => (elm._value));
```

but I get the value in brackets like [14.683000000000117]

How can I get the number in my *value* variable?

Thanks

Frank

Comment: `query.result[0][0]._value` map returns an array, so of cource its in brackets

Comment: `Array.prototype.map` **always** returns an array. If you don't want an array, don't use `map`. For instance, if you just want the first `_value` in the *first* array in `result`, then `query.result[0][0]._value` would give you that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map()` returns an array, even if it's an array of length 1. So, you want to retrieve the first element of the array it returns. You can achieve that by appending `[0]` at the end:

`value = query.result[0].map(elm => (elm._value))[0];`

Learn more on accessing array elements here, in the "Accessing Array Elements" section: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp